# Understanding the flow of stellar with federation server

Tags: stellar-sdk, federation

I have read the guides, check on other places, And I'm still confused about how federation works.

Lets say I monitor for deposits from our clients. We generate a unique ID (as a memo) and tell them to deposit to the address `<uniqueID>*ourDomain.com`. From that point I do not understand how the flow works.

Who calls the federation server (or service) to parse the address to an accountID with its memo? And if it's a request by our side to the federation server, do we take the response and use the account and memo in the request for a payment? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

Your client will use the federated address as a destination in their wallet software, the wallet will call your server and get the account info + memo when the client wants to send funds to you.

Comment: So if i understand what your'e saying is - customer type the address - his wallet send request to my domain to check what is the address and memo, and with that his wallet will make a payment request to that info right?

Comment: That's just right!

Comment: Ok, so the client does not do anything. i mean from the client side he only type the federated address as destiny and behind the scenes the wallet will make those 2 calls?